# Controls not being drawn on form during design time

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I was going along fine, then as I was trying to change the names of my controls all the controls on the tabpage disappeared.  The code in the design file is still there and I can see all the controls in the property window but if I select one nothing happens.  If I try to drop a new control on the form it appears.  The interesting thing about this is as I try to drop a new control on the form I see all the blue and pink lines that try to align the new control to existing controls

Here is the designer code

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class frmTaxInvoiceRegister
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
        components.Dispose()
    End If
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    Me.epValidator = New System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider(Me.components)
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister = New Common.CustomControls.TabControlDAI()
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister = New Common.CustomControls.TabPageDAI()
    Me.lblEndDate = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblStartDate = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.dtpEndDate = New System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker()
    Me.dtpStartDate = New System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker()
    Me.btnRunReport = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.grpTaxAddress = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.lblTaxAddress2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblTaxAddress3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox5 = New Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox()
    Me.lblTaxAddress1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox3 = New Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox()
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox4 = New Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox()
    Me.lblTaxId = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblOwnerName = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblReportType = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox2 = New Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox()
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox1 = New Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox()
    Me.cboReportType = New Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyComboBox()
    CType(Me.epValidator, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.SuspendLayout()
    Me.grpTaxAddress.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'epValidator
    '
    Me.epValidator.ContainerControl = Me
    '
    'tclTaxInvoiceRegister
    '
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.AllowPageInsert = False
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.AllowPageReplace = False
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister)
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(2, 2)
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.Name = "tclTaxInvoiceRegister"
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.SelectedIndex = 0
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(398, 360)
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.TabIndex = 0
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.ValidationResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None
    '
    'tpgTaxInvoiceRegister
    '
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.IgnoreValidation = False
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 22)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Name = "tpgTaxInvoiceRegister"
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(390, 334)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.TabIndex = 1017
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Text = "Tax Invoice Creation"
    '
    'lblEndDate
    '
    Me.lblEndDate.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblEndDate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(235, 101)
    Me.lblEndDate.Name = "lblEndDate"
    Me.lblEndDate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 13)
    Me.lblEndDate.TabIndex = 17
    Me.lblEndDate.Text = "End Date:"
    '
    'lblStartDate
    '
    Me.lblStartDate.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblStartDate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 101)
    Me.lblStartDate.Name = "lblStartDate"
    Me.lblStartDate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(58, 13)
    Me.lblStartDate.TabIndex = 16
    Me.lblStartDate.Text = "Start Date:"
    '
    'dtpEndDate
    '
    Me.dtpEndDate.CustomFormat = "MMM-yyyy"
    Me.dtpEndDate.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    Me.dtpEndDate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(296, 97)
    Me.dtpEndDate.Name = "dtpEndDate"
    Me.dtpEndDate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 20)
    Me.dtpEndDate.TabIndex = 15
    Me.dtpEndDate.Value = New Date(2012, 10, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    '
    'dtpStartDate
    '
    Me.dtpStartDate.CustomFormat = "MMM-yyyy"
    Me.dtpStartDate.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    Me.dtpStartDate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(77, 97)
    Me.dtpStartDate.Name = "dtpStartDate"
    Me.dtpStartDate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 20)
    Me.dtpStartDate.TabIndex = 14
    Me.dtpStartDate.Value = New Date(2012, 10, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    '
    'btnRunReport
    '
    Me.btnRunReport.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(147, 294)
    Me.btnRunReport.Name = "btnRunReport"
    Me.btnRunReport.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(97, 23)
    Me.btnRunReport.TabIndex = 13
    Me.btnRunReport.Text = "Create Tax File"
    Me.btnRunReport.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'grpTaxAddress
    '
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Controls.Add(Me.lblTaxAddress2)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Controls.Add(Me.lblTaxAddress3)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Controls.Add(Me.ReadOnlyTextBox5)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Controls.Add(Me.lblTaxAddress1)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Controls.Add(Me.ReadOnlyTextBox3)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Controls.Add(Me.ReadOnlyTextBox4)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 179)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Name = "grpTaxAddress"
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(379, 109)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.TabIndex = 11
    Me.grpTaxAddress.TabStop = False
    Me.grpTaxAddress.Text = "Tax Address"
    '
    'lblTaxAddress2
    '
    Me.lblTaxAddress2.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblTaxAddress2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 55)
    Me.lblTaxAddress2.Name = "lblTaxAddress2"
    Me.lblTaxAddress2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
    Me.lblTaxAddress2.TabIndex = 12
    Me.lblTaxAddress2.Text = "Line 2:"
    '
    'lblTaxAddress3
    '
    Me.lblTaxAddress3.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblTaxAddress3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 82)
    Me.lblTaxAddress3.Name = "lblTaxAddress3"
    Me.lblTaxAddress3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
    Me.lblTaxAddress3.TabIndex = 11
    Me.lblTaxAddress3.Text = "Line 3:"
    '
    'ReadOnlyTextBox5
    '
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(51, 79)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox5.Name = "ReadOnlyTextBox5"
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(312, 20)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox5.TabIndex = 5
    '
    'lblTaxAddress1
    '
    Me.lblTaxAddress1.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblTaxAddress1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 28)
    Me.lblTaxAddress1.Name = "lblTaxAddress1"
    Me.lblTaxAddress1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
    Me.lblTaxAddress1.TabIndex = 10
    Me.lblTaxAddress1.Text = "Line 1:"
    '
    'ReadOnlyTextBox3
    '
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(51, 25)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox3.Name = "ReadOnlyTextBox3"
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(312, 20)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox3.TabIndex = 3
    '
    'ReadOnlyTextBox4
    '
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(51, 52)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox4.Name = "ReadOnlyTextBox4"
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(312, 20)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox4.TabIndex = 4
    '
    'lblTaxId
    '
    Me.lblTaxId.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblTaxId.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 156)
    Me.lblTaxId.Name = "lblTaxId"
    Me.lblTaxId.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(40, 13)
    Me.lblTaxId.TabIndex = 8
    Me.lblTaxId.Text = "Tax Id:"
    '
    'lblOwnerName
    '
    Me.lblOwnerName.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblOwnerName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 130)
    Me.lblOwnerName.Name = "lblOwnerName"
    Me.lblOwnerName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(127, 13)
    Me.lblOwnerName.TabIndex = 7
    Me.lblOwnerName.Text = "Company / Owner Name:"
    '
    'lblReportType
    '
    Me.lblReportType.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblReportType.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 32)
    Me.lblReportType.Name = "lblReportType"
    Me.lblReportType.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(66, 13)
    Me.lblReportType.TabIndex = 6
    Me.lblReportType.Text = "Report Type"
    '
    'ReadOnlyTextBox2
    '
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(133, 153)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox2.Name = "ReadOnlyTextBox2"
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox2.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'ReadOnlyTextBox1
    '
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(133, 127)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox1.Name = "ReadOnlyTextBox1"
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(236, 20)
    Me.ReadOnlyTextBox1.TabIndex = 1
    '
    'cboReportType
    '
    Me.cboReportType.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.cboReportType.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(75, 29)
    Me.cboReportType.Name = "cboReportType"
    Me.cboReportType.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(294, 21)
    Me.cboReportType.TabIndex = 18
    '
    'frmTaxInvoiceRegister
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(404, 371)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister)
    Me.Name = "frmTaxInvoiceRegister"
    Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Me.Text = "Tax Invoice Register"
    CType(Me.epValidator, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.tclTaxInvoiceRegister.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.grpTaxAddress.PerformLayout()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
Friend WithEvents epValidator As System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider
Friend WithEvents tclTaxInvoiceRegister As Common.CustomControls.TabControlDAI
Friend WithEvents tpgTaxInvoiceRegister As Common.CustomControls.TabPageDAI
Friend WithEvents lblTaxId As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents lblOwnerName As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents lblReportType As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents ReadOnlyTextBox5 As Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox
Friend WithEvents ReadOnlyTextBox4 As Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox
Friend WithEvents ReadOnlyTextBox3 As Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox
Friend WithEvents ReadOnlyTextBox2 As Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox
Friend WithEvents ReadOnlyTextBox1 As Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyTextBox
Friend WithEvents grpTaxAddress As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents lblTaxAddress2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents lblTaxAddress3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents lblTaxAddress1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents ctlRestaurantSelector As Common.BusinessControls.Subway.RestaurantSelector
Friend WithEvents btnRunReport As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents dtpStartDate As System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
Friend WithEvents lblEndDate As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents lblStartDate As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents dtpEndDate As System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
Friend WithEvents cboReportType As Common.CustomControls.ReadOnlyComboBox
End Class
```

Here is what I see

[image: WTF]

Comment: whenever VS acts goofy on me: Clean solution. Exit. Delete .suo file. Try again.

Comment: Did that clean, clear gac as some of our common controls are in the gac, rebooted, see the comment below.  The code to add the controls to the tab page went missing?

Comment: Only a comment.  This is one reason I went to WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to actually add the controls to the tabpage container was missing

```
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.ctlRestaurantSelector)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.lblTaxId)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.lblOwnerName)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.lblReportType)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.ReadOnlyTextBox2)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.ReadOnlyTextBox1)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.grpTaxAddress)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.btnRunReport)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.dtpStartDate)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.lblEndDate)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.lblStartDate)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.dtpEndDate)
    Me.tpgTaxInvoiceRegister.Controls.Add(Me.cboReportType)
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The VS forms designers are trying to do something pretty difficult (safely execute part of your part-written program), which they don't always succeed at.  (I'm trying to be polite about VS here...)

When things like this go wrong, the best thing is to shut all the designer windows and any other windows open on source code from the same forms classes, then rebuild the complete application and then try going into the designer again.  If that doesn't work, then restarting VS might be necessary.

If you create circumstances where exceptions are thrown early in the life of your form (from a constructor, for example), then VS can really struggle with this.

Each version of VS tries to improve on this, but though I see the appearance of the failure changing, I never see much net improvement...

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  While reading through the code, and dropping a new control on the form I found that the controls are not added to the tabpage.  Again how this code disappeared I don't know because I was doing work trough the property window.  I just hope it stays because I know your not suppose to edit this file as Windows re-writes it with every change through the ui

Comment: I often edit the machine generated designer code - VS is very good at picking up changes from there - it's definitely a useful way to make related changes across a lot of controls without a lot of scratching-around with the mouse and property pages.